# Can I run a servo with lower voltage?

Tags: servomotor

I bought two servos ([HS-5685MH](http://hitecrcd.com/products/servos/sport-servos/digital-sport-servos/hs-5685mh-high-torque-hv-metal-gear-servo-/product)) for a pan-tilt-unit and somehow didn't see that they require 6.0 to 7.4 Volts which I don't have in my current setup. I have a 5V source that could provide the power, but I'm not sure what will happen to the motors if I use them with lower voltage.

Will they just be a bit slower or less powerful or could would I damage them with the lower voltage?

Answer (score 1):

Lower voltage is not going to damage the servos. Just don't expect them to operate as fast and provide as much torque as written in the docs. And they will be much easier to stall and draw the full 2.5A -- I hope your setup can provide that much without blowing the fuse.